# Override composer repositories locally

Tags: git, composer-php

Currently I am developing a repository `X` that is available on my private Packagist, which is the production version. However, for reasons of development speed, I am using a local repository from same project using symlink/junction.

**Something like that:**

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../plataform"
    }
],

"require": {
    "project/x": "dev-master"
},
```

But I when I commit a change ocurred on this `composer.json` I need always modify it to correct repository (removing `repositories` key and modifying `dev-master` to current version);

My doubt is: is possible create somekind of local override for that? I mean, a method to include an optional file that exists locally, but not remotely (production server) that will do this job without I need edit it before commit all the time.

**Pseudo-example:**

On official commit I should have something like:

```
"require": {
    "project/x": "~1.0"
},

"overrider": "composer.local.json"
```

And then if the `overrider` file is present, then it will be merged by the own `composer`.

`composer.local.json` file should be like:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../plataform"
        }
    ],

    "require": {
        "project/x": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this plugin [wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) that solves my problem totally. Tested and approved.

I just needed of `"replace": true` feature and include my local-only `composer.local.json` file.